# Revalidate JPanel's parent frame

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, parent, jpanel

I want my panel to fit the frame when I show/hide fields. How could I notify to the parent frame to revalidate?

I thought about pass the frame to my panel's constructor, but I think may have a way this is already done. I remember that there was a  protected attribute in JPanel, but there isn't.. maybe i remembering the wrong component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need show/hide some fields of my
>   panel, and I want the panel to fit the
>   frame.

You mean like a summary/details view and you want the frame size to change? Then try:

> SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...).pack();

Answer (score 1):

you could override the `addNotify` in the panel into something:

```
public void addNotify() {
    getParent().revalidate();
    repaint();
    super.addNotify();
}
```

Not sure if that's what you mean though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SwingUtilities.getRoot(this).invalidate();
```